# Custom actions in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I find that I often change specific cells from black on white to white on black when I'm making spreadsheets. It becomes tedious to change the background color, then the foreground color over and over for each header or highlighted cell I want in the spreadsheet.

What I would like to do is create a custom keyboard shortcut or something where I can click a cell, use a keyboard shortcut to flip the colors from black on white to white on black for whichever cell is highlighted.

Does anyone know a way to accomplish this?

Comment: there's no onClick trigger but a web app could do this where you drop in the ss url and click a button in the Ui that corresponds to the ss cell.  guess that 1 click would replace the 4 you are doing now?

Comment: Or a custom menu item to flip the selected range (3 clicks). If/when side bars are introduced for Sheets, 2 clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Once one cell has been formatted to suit and copied (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), you might select others with the arrow keys (to avoid clicks) and then do the following:

- right-click
- paste special
- paste format only